# How to detect namespace string in Javascript regular expression?

Tags: javascript

I need to check if a string represents a valid namespace format. A namespace is comprised of ids separated with dots. Each id starts with an alphabetic character and continues with an alphanumeric character.

Valid namespaces:

```
"com.company.package"
"com.company"
"com"
```

Invalid namespaces:

```
"1com.company.package"
"com.1company"
"com.com%any"
".com.company"
"com.company."
"com "
" com"
""
"."
"com..company"
```

Currently I use this simple regexp but it really don't check all of those invalid namespaces:

```
if( /^[\w\.]$/.test( namespaceStr ) ) {
  //valid namespace
} else {
  //invalid namespace
}
```

Any better suggestion for a small and efficient way to check if a string represents a valid namespace?

Here is a little jsfiddle that you can use for testing this regular expression: http://jsfiddle.net/bA85y/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Edit:** This one should work for every case:

```
/^(?:[a-z]\d*(?:\.[a-z])?)+$/i
```

If you don't care about capturing groups even shorter:

```
/^([a-z]\d*(\.[a-z])?)+$/i
```

A little explanation:

```
^ // Start
( // Open group
[a-z]\d* // Must start by letter and may be followed by a number (greedy)
(\.[a-z])? // It may be followed by a dot only if it's followed by a letter (non-greedy)
)+ // Close group and match at least once so we get rid of empty values
$ // Ends, not allow any other characters
```

**Demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/elclanrs/5hnQV/

Comment: Added a better regex, that should do it for most of those cases.

Comment: check this string by your pattern: `com.company.package.1`

Comment: there's something wrong yet!
*Each id starts with an alphabetic character and continues with an alphanumeric character* so why this string can not be valid? `com.company4` or `c0m`

Comment: Not sure if thats valid but I think it would be as simple as adding `\d*` `/^(?:[a-z]\d*\.?)+[^.\s\d]$/i`. Haven't tried.

Comment: +1 good one and very nice example! Could you explain that regex a little furhter pls?

Comment: that problem is not solved, `com.company4` is not valid by your pattern. I dunno why did you complicate the solution. It can be solved much easier.

Comment: Well it's not entirely clear what OP really wants since he hasn't posted anything yet, but this should do if matching `com.campany4` is necessary `/^(?:[a-z]\d*(?:\.[a-z])?)+$/i`

Comment: if I understand correctly the `(:?` part prevents the regex engine from creating backreferences. But I have two questions: 1. does the test() function return backreferences at all? 2. is it really more optimized when we use this syntax?

Answer (score 2):

Try this pattern:

```
/^[a-z][a-z0-9]*(?:\.[a-z][a-z0-9]*)*$/i
```

**EDIT:**
this is a reversion of @elclanrs [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5hnQV/4/)

Comment: Almost the same as mine, but I think yours is better as it doesn't capture the group with the "?:". I think you just should add the 'i' flag.

Comment: @Pato, you're right, but I just wanted to show how pattern should be, excepting the flags :D

Comment: @HashemQolami: In JS you can use `\d` instead of `0-9` you can save some bytes right there. Just a tip. xD

Answer (score 2):

I think you are looking for this:

```
/^[a-z][a-z0-9]*(\.[a-z][a-z0-9]*)*$/i
```

**EDIT:**

This one is a little better (with `?:` and `\d` inspired by @HashemQolami and @elclanrs):

```
/^[a-z][a-z\d]*(?:\.[a-z][a-z\d]*)*$/i
```

And this one is shorter but does the same job:

```
/^[a-z](?:[a-z\d]*(?:\.[a-z])?)*$/i
```

And this one too, using lookahead to test that it doesn't end with a `.`:

```
/^(?!.*\.$)(?:[a-z][a-z\d]*\.?)+$/i
```

Please note that the selected answer doesn't work with "a.b.c" or in some cases with more than two levels.

**UPDATE:**

I've made a little (very basic) test:

```
var valid = [
"com.company.package",
"com.company",
"com.company1",
"com1.company1",
"a.b.c",
"a1.b.c3.d",
"a1.b2.c3.d4"];

var invalid = [
"1com.company.package",
"com.1company",
"com.com%any",
".com.company",
"com.company.",
"com ",
" com",
"",
".",
"com..company"];

function testRegex(regex, list)
{
    var res=[];
    for(var i=0; i<list.length; i++)
    {
        if(regex.test(list[i]))
            res.push(list[i] + " ==> matched");
        else
            res.push(list[i] + " ==> NOT matched");
    }

    return res.join('<br>');
}

var regex = /^[a-z][a-z0-9]*(\.[a-z][a-z0-9]*)*$/i;


var html = "<p>VALID</p>";
html += testRegex(regex, valid);
html += "<p>INVALID</p>";
html += testRegex(regex, invalid);

document.write("<div>" + html + "</div>");
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on @dionyziz answer this work:

```
/^[a-z]+(\.[a-z]+)*[^.\s]$/
```

Answer (score -1):

The following regular expression will do what you need. It checks for an alphabetic string and then allows multiple other alphabetic strings separated by a dot.

```
/^[a-z]+(\.[a-z]+)*$/
```

Comment: Thank you @AlexStack, I fixed the regular expression.