# Delete item from object by selector string

Tags: javascript

I am trying to delete an item from an object by passing a key to the method. For example I want to delete `a1`, and to do so I pass `a.a1` to the method. It then should delete `a1` from the object leaving the rest of the object alone.

This is the structure of the object:

```
this.record = {
  id: '',
  expiration: 0,
  data: {
    a: {
      a1: 'Cat'
    }
  }
}
```

I then call this method:

```
delete(key) {
  let path = key.split('.')
  let data = path.reduce((obj, key) => typeof obj == 'object' ? obj[key] : null, this.record.data)
  if(data) delete data
}
```

Like this:

```
let inst = new MyClass()
inst.delete('a.a1')
```

This however gives me the following error:

> ```
> delete data;
>        ^^^^
> ```
>
> SyntaxError: Delete of an unqualified identifier in strict mode.

I assume that `data` is a reference still at this point, or is it not?

Maybe `reduce` isn't the right method to use here. How can I delete the item from the object?

Comment: This may not be an efficient answer, but you could flatten the object, delete the key, and the unflatten it. There are several libraries out there that can do the heavy lifting for you. Here's one: https://github.com/hughsk/flat

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using your example, the value of `data` at the point where it is checked for truthiness is `Cat`, the *value* of the property you're trying to delete. At this point, `data` is just a regular variable that's referencing a string and it's no longer in the context of `inst`.

Here's a solution I managed to get to work using the one from your OP as the basis:

```
let path = key.split('.')
let owningObject = path.slice(0, path.length - 1)
    .reduce((obj, key) => typeof obj == 'object' ? obj[key] : null, this.record.data)

if (owningObject) delete owningObject[path[path.length - 1]]
```

The main difference between this and what you had is that `reduce` operates on a *slice* of the path segments, which does not include the final identifier: This ends up with `owningObject` being a reference to the `a` object. The `reduce` is really just navigating along the path up until the penultimate segment, which itself is used as the property name that gets deleted.

For an invalid path, it bails out either because of the `if (owningObject)` or because using `delete` on an unknown property is a no-op anyway.

Comment: It took me an embarrassing amount of time to realize how `owningObject` was being calculated. How does this work on invalid paths would you say?

Comment: Just tested on `a1.abc.efg`, and it doesn't throw errors or seem to go rouge and delete things.

Comment: I also changed `if(owningObject !== undefined)` and instead of setting `null` I set `undefined` since it wouldn't delete if the value of `owningObject` is `false` or `null`

Answer (score 1):

The solution I came up with which I am not super fond of but works, is looping over the items which will allow me to do long keys like this

- `a.a1`
- `a.a1.a1-1`
- `a.a1.a1-1.sub`

The function then looks like this

```js
let record = {
  data: {
    a: {
      a1: 'Cat',
      a2: {
        val: 'Dog'
      }
    }
  }
}

function remove(key) {
  let path = key.split('.')
  let obj = record.data
  for (let i = 0; i < path.length; i++) {
    if (i + 1 == path.length && obj && obj[path[i]]) delete obj[path[i]]
    else if(obj && obj[path[i]]) obj = obj[path[i]]
    else obj = null
  }
}

// Removes `a.a1`
remove('a.a1')
console.log(JSON.stringify(record))

// Removes `a.a2.val`
remove('a.a2.val')
console.log(JSON.stringify(record))

// Removes nothing since the path is invalid
remove('a.a2.val.asdf.fsdf')
console.log(JSON.stringify(record))
```

Comment: What do you dislike about the solution?

Comment: I just tried the reduce example I posted with the same test cases that you have here and it gives the same results. What made you switch from a reduce approach to a for-loop?

Answer (score 0):

You can delete keys using [] references.

```
var foo = {
  a: 1,
  b: 2
};
var selector = "a";
delete foo[selector];
console.log(foo);
```

I'm not sure if this helps you but it might help someone googling to this question.

Answer (score 0):

Here's another method which is very similar to the OP's own solution but uses `Array.prototype.forEach` to iterate over the path parts. I came to this result independently in my attempt to wrap this up as elegantly as possible.

```js
function TestRecord(id, data) {
    let record = {
        id : id,
        data : data
    };

    function removeDataProperty(key) {
        let parent = record.data;
        let parts = key.split('.');
        let l = parts.length - 1;
        parts.forEach((p, i) => {
            if (i < l && parent[p]) parent = parent[p];
            else if (i == l && parent[p]) delete parent[p];
            else throw new Error('invalid key');
        });
    }

  return {
    record : record,
    remove : function(key) {
        try {
            removeDataProperty(key);
        } catch (e) {
            console.warn(`key ${key} not found`);
        }
    }
  }
}

let test = new TestRecord('TESTA', {
  a : { a1 : '1', a2 : '2' },
  b : { c : { d : '3' } }
});

test.remove('a'); // root level properties are supported
test.remove('b.c.d'); // deep nested properties are supported
test.remove('a.b.x'); // early exit loop and warn that property not found

console.log(test.record.data);
```

The usage of `throw` in this example is for the purpose of breaking out of the loop early if any part of the path is invalid since `forEach` does not support the `break` statement.

By the way, there is evidence that `forEach` is slower than a simple `for` loop but if the dataset is small enough or the readability vs efficiency tradeoff is acceptable for your use case then this may be a good alternative.

https://hackernoon.com/javascript-performance-test-for-vs-for-each-vs-map-reduce-filter-find-32c1113f19d7

Answer (score -1):

This may not be the most elegant solution but you could achieve the desired result very quickly and easily by using `eval()`.

```
function TestRecord(id) {
  let record = {
    id : id,
    data : {
      a : {
        a1 : 'z',
        a2 : 'y'
      }
    }
  };

  return {
    record : record,
    remove : function (key) {
      if (!key.match(/^(?!.*\.$)(?:[a-z][a-z\d]*\.?)+$/i)) {
        console.warn('invalid path');
        return;      
      } else {
        let cmd = 'delete this.record.data.' + key;
        eval(cmd);      
      }
    }    
  };
}

let t = new TestRecord('TESTA');
t.remove('a.a1');
console.log(t.record.data);
```

I have included a [regular expression from another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12910967/6036546) that validates the user input against the namespace format to prevent abuse/misuse.

By the way, I also used the method name `remove` instead of `delete` since delete is a [reserved keyword in javascript](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Lexical_grammar#Keywords).

Also, before the anti-eval downvotes start pouring in. From: https://humanwhocodes.com/blog/2013/06/25/eval-isnt-evil-just-misunderstood/ :

> ...you shouldn’t be afraid to use it when you have a case where eval()
>   makes sense. Try not using it first, but don’t let anyone scare you
>   into thinking your code is more fragile or less secure when eval() is
>   used appropriately.

I'm not promoting eval as the best way to manipulate objects (obviously a well defined object with a good interface would be the proper solution) but for the specific use-case of deleting a nested key from an object by passing a namespaced string as input, I don't think any amount of looping or parsing would be more efficient or succinct.